# how to load mysql data from hdfs into pyspark

Tags: mysql, pyspark, sqoop

I used sqoop to import table from mysql to hdfs location /user/cloudera/table1, now what should be the command to load this table into pyspark code. I am just writing simple code as below.. I am using cloudera CDH 5.13. Thanks

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
if __name__ == "__main__":
 # create Spark context with Spark configuration
 conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count")
 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
 data = code here to import table from hdfs
```

Comment: What format is your file in the hdfs?

Comment: i just used command --> 
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/database1 --username root --password cloudera --table customers

Comment: Can you see the format of the file in hdfs? If it's avro/parquet/csv/txt?

Comment: can you please let me know how to check.. and thanks for helping on this :)

Comment: Using `hdfs dfs -ls`, Find your file and see the format

Comment: `[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls  
Found 6 items  
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2019-11-12 20:31 .sparkStaging  
drwx------   - cloudera cloudera          0 2019-11-12 16:17 .staging  
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2019-11-10 17:50 customers  
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2019-11-12 16:17 filterdOrders  
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2019-11-12 14:35 orders  
drwxr-xr-x   - cloudera cloudera          0 2019-11-12 15:00 residents`

Comment: it doesn show file format here... customers is my table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202242/discussion-between-user2774120-and-pissall).

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop by default imports data as text format or we can explicitly set it using (--as-textfile) option.

Refer : [Sqoop Documentation](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1764646)
Read 7.2.8. File Formats for better understanding.

To see file format manually use hdfs cat command.

ls for listing files under path.
cat for opening selected files.

You can use hdfs as well instead of hadoop in below commands.

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/table1
hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/table1/samplefile.txt
```

Note : If data is in readable format then it is text format.

For importing data from hdfs in pyspark you can use textFile option.

```
textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://namenodehost/user/cloudera/table1/samplefile.txt")
textFile.first()
```

Refer : [reading-a-file-in-hdfs-from-pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835649/reading-a-file-in-hdfs-from-pyspark)